# why python hash_ring is so slow?

Tags: python, memcached

well,I found hash_ring.MemcacheRing's so slow that rate test cant beat directly db access
while,I replace it with memcache.Client，rate test's  back to normal
rps is tested in multithreaded environment

`memcache.Client rps2500

hash_ring.MemcacheRing rps 600

directly db access:rps960`

I use hotshot to track hash_ring.MemcacheRing,I found there's definitely something wrong with hash_ring,u can find that hash_ring cost too much cpu as expected in the following 
profile data collected
hotshot profile data's collected in single threaded environment

```
 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    10000    0.066    0.000    8.297    0.001 Memcached.py:16(__getitem__)
    10000    0.262    0.000    6.544    0.001 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:818(_unsafe_get)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /usr/local/Python-2.6.4/lib/python2.6/socket.py:180(__init__)
    20000    0.064    0.000    0.064    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:310(_statlog)
    80000    0.118    0.000    0.118    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/hash_ring/hash_ring.py:148()
    10000    0.148    0.000    8.168    0.001 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:812(_get)
    20000    0.086    0.000    0.157    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:1086(_get_socket)
    30000   10.539    0.000   10.539    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:1118(readline)
    10000    0.102    0.000    0.102    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:1142(recv)
    20000    0.243    0.000    0.243    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/hash_ring/hash_ring.py:156(_hash_digest)
    20000    0.103    0.000    0.103    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/hash_ring/hash_ring.py:124(distinct_filter)
    10000    0.167    0.000    0.269    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:965(_recv_value)
        1    0.148    0.148   15.701   15.701 Memcached.py:25(foo)
    10000    0.236    0.000    5.409    0.001 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:953(_expectvalue)
    20002    0.336    0.000    0.336    0.000 :1(settimeout)
    10000    0.061    0.000    7.207    0.001 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:541(set)
    20000    0.116    0.000    0.606    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/hash_ring/hash_ring.py:141(gen_key)
    20000    0.279    0.000    1.680    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/hash_ring/memcache_ring.py:20(_get_server)
    40000    0.346    0.000    1.236    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/hash_ring/hash_ring.py:111(iterate_nodes)
    10000    0.144    0.000    7.146    0.001 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:771(_set)
    20000    0.129    0.000    0.247    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/hash_ring/hash_ring.py:150(_hash_val)
    20000    0.098    0.000    0.433    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:1111(send_cmd)
    10000    0.063    0.000    8.231    0.001 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:857(get)
    10000    0.049    0.000    7.256    0.001 Memcached.py:13(__setitem__)
    20000    0.144    0.000    5.510    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:1135(expect)
    20000    0.181    0.000    0.787    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/hash_ring/hash_ring.py:92(get_node_pos)
    20000    0.070    0.000    0.070    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:1070(_check_dead)
    10000    0.084    0.000    0.084    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:725(_val_to_store_info)
    20000    0.068    0.000    0.225    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:1076(connect)
    20000    1.036    0.000    1.036    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:1000(check_key)
    10000    0.216    0.000    5.702    0.001 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:777(_unsafe_set)
        0    0.000             0.000          profile:0(profiler)
```

and the following is memcache.Client's profile data

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    10000    0.064    0.000    8.022    0.001 Memcached.py:16(__getitem__)
    10000    0.263    0.000    6.885    0.001 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:818(_unsafe_get)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /usr/local/Python-2.6.4/lib/python2.6/socket.py:180(__init__)
    20000    0.069    0.000    0.069    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:310(_statlog)
    10000    0.127    0.000    7.897    0.001 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:812(_get)
    20000    0.091    0.000    0.164    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:1086(_get_socket)
    30000   11.074    0.000   11.074    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:1118(readline)
    10000    0.098    0.000    0.098    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:1142(recv)
    20000    0.259    0.000    0.568    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:329(_get_server)
        1    0.149    0.149   15.036   15.036 Memcached.py:25(foo)
    10000    0.236    0.000    5.645    0.001 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:953(_expectvalue)
    20002    0.351    0.000    0.351    0.000 :1(settimeout)
    10000    0.064    0.000    6.814    0.001 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:541(set)
    10000    0.124    0.000    6.751    0.001 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:771(_set)
    20000    1.039    0.000    1.039    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:1000(check_key)
    20000    0.092    0.000    0.442    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:1111(send_cmd)
    10000    0.061    0.000    7.958    0.001 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:857(get)
    10000    0.050    0.000    6.864    0.001 Memcached.py:13(__setitem__)
    20000    0.148    0.000    5.812    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:1135(expect)
    20000    0.073    0.000    0.073    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:1070(_check_dead)
    10000    0.087    0.000    0.087    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:725(_val_to_store_info)
    20000    0.072    0.000    0.236    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:1076(connect)
    20000    0.072    0.000    0.072    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:57(cmemcache_hash)
    10000    0.218    0.000    5.905    0.001 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:777(_unsafe_set)
        0    0.000             0.000          profile:0(profiler)
    10000    0.156    0.000    0.255    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:965(_recv_value)
```

and profile data's following

```
 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    20000    2.278    0.000    4.260    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:1000(check_key)
   640000    1.624    0.000    1.624    0.000 :0(ord)
    20000    0.658    0.000    1.445    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:329(_get_server)
   100010    0.477    0.000    0.477    0.000 :0(len)
    30000    0.460    0.000    0.827    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:1118(readline)
   110000    0.414    0.000    0.414    0.000 :0(isinstance)
    20000    0.412    0.000    0.412    0.000 :0(sendall)
    10000    0.349    0.000    1.974    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:818(_unsafe_get)
    10000    0.344    0.000    0.633    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:725(_val_to_store_info)
    10000    0.344    0.000    2.006    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:777(_unsafe_set)
    10000    0.325    0.000    0.624    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:965(_recv_value)
    50000    0.233    0.000    0.233    0.000 :0(find)
    20000    0.200    0.000    0.808    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:1135(expect)
    10000    0.194    0.000    5.292    0.001 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:812(_get)
    20000    0.190    0.000    0.357    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:1076(connect)
    10000    0.185    0.000    4.771    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:771(_set)
    10000    0.173    0.000    0.187    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:1142(recv)
    10000    0.163    0.000    0.400    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:953(_expectvalue)
    20000    0.152    0.000    0.564    0.000 :1(sendall)
    20000    0.147    0.000    0.711    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:1111(send_cmd)
    20000    0.142    0.000    0.232    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:57(cmemcache_hash)
```

```
 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    20000    2.679    0.000    4.921    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:1000(check_key)
   640000    2.125    0.000    2.125    0.000 :0(ord)
    20000    0.636    0.000    2.887    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/hash_ring/memcache_ring.py:20(_get_server)
    20000    0.582    0.000    1.673    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/hash_ring/hash_ring.py:92(get_node_pos)
    30000    0.565    0.000    0.979    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:1118(readline)
    20000    0.345    0.000    0.630    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/hash_ring/hash_ring.py:156(_hash_digest)
    40000    0.328    0.000    2.065    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/hash_ring/hash_ring.py:111(iterate_nodes)
    20003    0.294    0.000    0.294    0.000 :0(recv)
    10000    0.287    0.000    1.119    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:953(_expectvalue)
    10000    0.176    0.000    4.437    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:771(_set)
    10000    0.175    0.000    1.697    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:818(_unsafe_get)
    10000    0.160    0.000    5.899    0.001 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:812(_get)
    20000    0.157    0.000    1.051    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/hash_ring/hash_ring.py:141(gen_key)
    10000    0.148    0.000    0.251    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/memcache.py:965(_recv_value)
    20000    0.144    0.000    0.264    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/hash_ring/hash_ring.py:150(_hash_val)
    90000    0.122    0.000    0.122    0.000 :0(isinstance)
    50000    0.120    0.000    0.120    0.000 :0(find)
    80000    0.120    0.000    0.120    0.000 build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/hash_ring/hash_ring.py:148()
```